# custom number formatting in rdlc report

Tags: rdlc, number-formatting

Is there a way in rdlc reports to format numbers as such:-

add thousand separators but leave decimal places as is, so

1000.00 --> 1,000.00

1000 --> 1,000

Answer (score 2):

Absolutely, in TextBox properties window select Number tab, select "Number" category and choose how you want to format your number:

[image]