# how to give comma for values in rdlc expression

Tags: asp.net, expression, rdlc

How to give comma for a sum of values in rdlc report. Given below is my exressions.

```
=ROUND(Sum(Fields!gross_val.Value))
```

current output: `2368`
expected output: `2,368`

```
=Format(Sum(Fields!qty.Value*Fields!po_rt.Value),"F2")
```

current output: `1027.34`
expected output: `1,027.34`

Please help me to find a proper solution. Thank you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36238823/custom-number-formatting-in-rdlc-report/36265331#36265331

Answer (score 2):

Referecing MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa241719(v=vs.60).aspx have you tried using "##,##0.##" as your format instead of "F2"